# format output in Perl

Tags: perl, format

I've build a perl script that collect data from power system, the information that collect is cpu ent capacity ram ecc ecc

So here the output of my script

```
Server Server-9119-MHE-xxxxxx Active CPU 48.0 Installed CPU 64.0
------------------------------------------------------------------

HOSTNAME Memory Phisical_CPU Type logical_CPU logical_SMT_CPU OS_Version Mode Weight VirtCPU MaxVirtCpu
xxxx  49152 MB  1.50  Shared-SMT-4  2 8 7100-04-03-1642  Uncapped  128   32
xxxxxxx  32768 MB  0,10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7100-04-00-0000  Uncapped  80   32
xxxxxxx-xxxx  32768 MB  0.10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  128   4
xxxxxxx-xxxx  32768 MB  0.10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  80   4
xxxx 335872 MB  3,00  Shared-SMT-4  8 32 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  128   32
xxxxxxxxx  32768 MB  0.30  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  80   32
xxxxxxxxxx  65536 MB  2.00  Shared-SMT  4 8 5300-12-09-1341  Uncapped  128   8
xxxxxxxxx  184320 MB  2.00  Shared-SMT-8  8 64 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  100   8
xxxxxxx  25600 MB  0.50  Shared-SMT  1 2 5300-12-09-1341  Uncapped  80   8
xxxxxxxxxx  65536 MB  1.40  Shared-SMT-4  2 8 7200-00-03-1642  Uncapped  128   20
xxxxxxx  614400 MB  15.50  Shared-SMT-4  20 80 7100-04-03-1642  Uncapped  200   64
xxxxxxx  614400 MB  15.50  Shared-SMT-4  20 80 7100-04-03-1642  Uncapped  200   64
xxxxx  8192 MB  3.00  Shared-SMT-4  5 20 6100-09-06-1543  Uncapped  255   8
xxxxx  8192 MB  3.00  Shared-SMT-4  5 20 6100-09-06-1543  Uncapped  255   8

Server Server-9119-MHE-xxxxxx Active CPU 48.0 Installed CPU 64.0
------------------------------------------------------------------

HOSTNAME Memory Phisical_CPU Type logical_CPU logical_SMT_CPU OS_Version Mode Weight VirtCPU MaxVirtCpu
xxxxx 65536 MB  1,00  Shared-SMT-8  4 32 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  220   32
xxxxxx 32768 MB  0.10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7200-00-03-1642  Uncapped  100   32
xxxxx_xxxxxx  32768 MB  0.10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7200-00-03-1642  Uncapped  80   32
xxxx-xxxxx  32768 MB  0.10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  128   4
xxxx-xxxxx  32768 MB  0.10  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  80   4
xxxxxx  335872 MB  3,00  Shared-SMT-4  8 32 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  128   8
xxxxxx  24576 MB  0,20  Shared-SMT-4  1 4 6100-08-02-1316  Uncapped  80   10
xxxxxx  73728 MB  2.00  Shared-SMT  4 8 5300-12-09-1341  Uncapped  128   8
xxxxxxxx  16384 MB  1.00  Shared-SMT  2 4 5300-12-09-1341  Uncapped  100   8
xxxxxxxx  32768 MB  0.50  Shared-SMT  2 4 5300-12-09-1341  Uncapped  100   32
xxxxx  65536 MB  2,20  Shared-SMT-8  8 64 7100-05-05-1939  Uncapped  100   32
xxxxx_xxx  powerd off
xxxxxxxx  32768 MB  0.50  Shared-SMT-4  2 8 7200-00-03-1642  Capped  0   8
xxxxx  614400 MB  15.50  Shared-SMT-4  20 80 7100-04-03-1642  Uncapped  200   64
xxxxx  614400 MB  15.50  Shared-SMT-4  20 80 7100-04-03-1642  Uncapped  200   64
xxxxx  8192 MB  3.00  Shared-SMT-4  5 20 6100-09-06-1543  Uncapped  255   8
xxxxx  8192 MB  3.00  Shared-SMT-4  5 20 6100-09-06-1543  Uncapped  255   8
```

There is a simple way to use array and format the output in a table?
I' don't know for example multi dimensional array or something like a function in perl that help me to build a formatted table output

here the code

```
@power_server=`/usr/bin/ssh  hscroot\@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'lssyscfg -r sys -F name'`;
chomp @power_server;
my @arr;
foreach $i (@power_server) {
        ##Collect CPU installed and active
        $cpu=`/usr/bin/ssh  hscroot\@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'lshwres -r proc -m $i --level sys -F configurable_sys_proc_units,installed_sys_proc_units'`;
        @cpu_split=split (/,/, $cpu);
        print "\nServer $i Active CPU @cpu_split[0] Installed CPU @cpu_split[1]";
        print "------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
        printf "%-18s %12s %12s %-12s %11s %15s %-16s %-8s %6s %7s %10s \nHOSTNAME Memory Phisical_CPU Type logical_CPU logical_SMT_CPU OS_Version Mode Weight VirtCPU MaxVirtCpu \n";
        @lpar=`/usr/bin/ssh  hscroot\@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx lssyscfg -m $i -r lpar -F name`;
        chomp @lpar;
                foreach $z (@lpar) {
                        $ip_addr=`/usr/bin/ssh  hscroot\@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'lssyscfg -m $i -r lpar --filter lpar_names=$z -F rmc_ipaddr'`;
                        chop $ip_addr;
                        ####check ip
                        #print "$ip_addr \n";
                        #print "$z $i\n";
                        if ($ip_addr eq ''){
                                print "\n$z  powerd off \n";
                        }
                        else {
                                
                                $hostname=single_command_ret("/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr hostname");
                                chop $hostname;
                                $memory=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep "Online Memory" |awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}'`;
                                chop $memory;
                                $ent=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep "Entitled Capacity"|grep -v Pool| awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}'`;
                                chop $ent;
                                $type=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep "Type" |awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}'`;
                                chop $type;
                                $logicacpu=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep "Online Virtual CPUs" |awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}'`;
                                chop $logicacpu;
                                $virtualcpu=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr vmstat | grep "System configuration" | awk -F'[ =]' '{print \$4}'`;
                                chop $virtualcpu;
                                $oslevel=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr oslevel -s`;
                                chop $oslevel;
                                $mode=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep -E "^Mode" |awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}`;
                                chop $mode;
                                $weight=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep "Variable Capacity Weight"|grep -v Desired |awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}'`;
                                chop $weight;
                                $maxvirtcpu=`/usr/bin/ssh $ip_addr lparstat -i |grep "Maximum Virtual CPUs" |awk 'FS="\:"{print \$2}'`;
                                chop $maxvirtcpu;
                                printf "%-18s %12s %12s %-12s %11s %15s %-16s %-8s %6s %7s %10s\n$hostname $memory $ent $type $logicacpu $virtualcpu $oslevel $mode $weight $logicacpu $maxvirtcpu";
                                
                                
                                
                                
                        }
            
                }

              
} 
sub single_command_ret
{
        local ($command) = $_[0] ;
        local $tmp=`$command`;
        chop ($tmp);
        return ("$tmp");
}
```

Comment: [Text::Table](http://p3rl.org/Text::Table)

Comment: Use of [format](https://www.learning-perl.com/2014/07/formats/) could help.